# Grabbing monthly data from SAR and showing clean results

Tags: linux, bash, sar

Im trying to write something in bash to show the data logged by sar for the month. What I have so far is

```html
for file in /var/log/sa/sa??; do sar -q -f "$file" | grep "^.\{35\}1[1-9][0-9]"; done
```

This shows the data that I want in that it shows any time the load was over 110, the problem is that it just shows the hours that this happened, not the day. Here is some example output:

```html
# for file in /var/log/sa/sa??; do sar -q -f "$file" | grep "^.\{35\}1[1-9][0-9]"; done
02:57:01 AM        72      1318    142.61     54.60     29.89
02:58:19 AM       137      1366    135.52     71.45     37.77
01:20:10 AM       205      1246    112.29     55.22     38.40
01:22:02 AM       109      1260    195.54    102.06     57.06
01:23:01 AM        63      1219    128.44    100.63     59.44
01:26:02 AM       113      1380    120.67     99.85     65.70
01:27:02 AM       133      1371    133.72    107.76     70.58
01:28:12 AM       178      1280    120.40    108.98     73.71
03:50:02 AM       121      1443    189.25    168.81     82.88
05:56:17 AM       208      1231    113.36     41.01     20.65
05:57:06 AM       145      1227    128.45     56.78     27.11
05:58:06 AM       160      1265    149.87     74.99     35.18
05:59:01 AM       136      1370    179.49     95.48     44.45
06:00:01 AM        93      1404    156.11    105.23     51.06
06:01:01 AM        34      1310    119.41    105.12     54.48
10:07:04 AM       169      1524    110.05     82.17     55.00
10:08:01 AM       105      1466    122.00     91.18     59.82
02:26:10 AM       181      1276    149.12     62.34     34.25
02:27:05 AM       137      1327    169.27     81.70     42.43
12:02:01 AM        49      1326    110.65     57.31     39.68
07:29:02 PM       136      1279    116.35     47.18     23.75
07:30:01 PM       124      1378    116.51     58.86     29.10
07:31:03 PM        93      1200    123.80     71.66     35.50
07:32:01 PM       113      1324    138.65     84.84     42.10
07:33:01 PM        76      1411    119.29     89.63     46.45
08:55:08 PM       126      1362    112.14     64.36     42.02
08:56:01 PM        84      1571    166.07     87.82     51.24
09:04:01 PM        91      1404    146.57     97.72     65.50
09:19:07 PM        87      1250    112.83     48.03     46.85
09:40:01 PM        87      1290    118.10     72.67     57.32
09:46:03 PM       113      1215    110.39     71.43     59.69
11:53:03 PM       101      1341    116.01     52.90     37.79
02:04:10 AM       257      1382    139.37     61.42     43.58
08:52:01 AM        84      1541    112.46     59.07     39.06
09:44:01 AM       111      1579    161.68     77.07     45.34
09:46:01 PM       105      1348    111.06     65.09     45.65
10:31:01 PM       120      1410    124.08     61.14     44.57
10:35:01 PM        83      1515    115.66     79.33     54.93
01:06:01 AM       137      1379    114.34     57.90     41.89
01:56:08 AM       216      1290    113.14     59.06     40.92
02:06:01 AM       135      1474    126.60     79.41     55.15
02:28:35 AM       267      1225    151.81     69.58     59.47
02:29:01 AM        97      1360    144.64     76.03     61.96
02:41:02 AM       144      1279    133.04     60.48     52.53
10:06:07 AM       304      1415    128.59     72.30     51.68
12:27:01 AM       121      1399    112.99     54.63     40.77
03:20:01 AM       149      1450    120.17     58.10     36.52
10:11:01 PM       136      1449    120.49     70.64     48.13
10:12:02 PM       121      1468    143.77     87.26     55.30
10:29:01 PM        64      1362    116.96     60.23     49.71
04:07:37 AM       170      1307    110.13     46.58     35.07
03:29:01 AM        97      1217    120.40     57.09     33.87
03:30:04 AM       139      1347    165.79     81.46     43.68
03:31:05 AM       105      1379    159.32     96.09     51.29
03:32:01 AM       194      1294    153.11    105.79     57.25
```

What I need to do is to either write the file name above each set of hours, or find a way to get the full date from sar (which from reading the man doesnt seem to be possible.)
Any help would be appreciated.

An example of the desired output would be something like

```html
/var/log/sa/sa15
2:57:01 AM        72      1318    142.61     54.60     29.89
02:58:19 AM       137      1366    135.52     71.45     37.77
01:20:10 AM       205      1246    112.29     55.22     38.40
01:22:02 AM       109      1260    195.54    102.06     57.06
01:23:01 AM        63      1219    128.44    100.63     59.44
01:26:02 AM       113      1380    120.67     99.85     65.70
01:27:02 AM       133      1371    133.72    107.76     70.58
01:28:12 AM       178      1280    120.40    108.98     73.71
03:50:02 AM       121      1443    189.25    168.81     82.88
05:56:17 AM       208      1231    113.36     41.01     20.65
05:57:06 AM       145      1227    128.45     56.78     27.11
05:58:06 AM       160      1265    149.87     74.99     35.18
05:59:01 AM       136      1370    179.49     95.48     44.45
06:00:01 AM        93      1404    156.11    105.23     51.06
/var/log/sa/sa17
06:01:01 AM        34      1310    119.41    105.12     54.48
10:07:04 AM       169      1524    110.05     82.17     55.00
10:08:01 AM       105      1466    122.00     91.18     59.82
02:26:10 AM       181      1276    149.12     62.34     34.25
02:27:05 AM       137      1327    169.27     81.70     42.43
12:02:01 AM        49      1326    110.65     57.31     39.68
07:29:02 PM       136      1279    116.35     47.18     23.75
07:30:01 PM       124      1378    116.51     58.86     29.10
07:31:03 PM        93      1200    123.80     71.66     35.50
07:32:01 PM       113      1324    138.65     84.84     42.10
07:33:01 PM        76      1411    119.29     89.63     46.45
08:55:08 PM       126      1362    112.14     64.36     42.02
08:56:01 PM        84      1571    166.07     87.82     51.24
09:04:01 PM        91      1404    146.57     97.72     65.50
09:19:07 PM        87      1250    112.83     48.03     46.85
09:40:01 PM        87      1290    118.10     72.67     57.32
09:46:03 PM       113      1215    110.39     71.43     59.69
11:53:03 PM       101      1341    116.01     52.90     37.79
02:04:10 AM       257      1382    139.37     61.42     43.58
08:52:01 AM        84      1541    112.46     59.07     39.06
09:44:01 AM       111      1579    161.68     77.07     45.34
/var/log/sa/sa19
09:46:01 PM       105      1348    111.06     65.09     45.65
10:31:01 PM       120      1410    124.08     61.14     44.57
10:35:01 PM        83      1515    115.66     79.33     54.93
01:06:01 AM       137      1379    114.34     57.90     41.89
01:56:08 AM       216      1290    113.14     59.06     40.92
02:06:01 AM       135      1474    126.60     79.41     55.15
02:28:35 AM       267      1225    151.81     69.58     59.47
02:29:01 AM        97      1360    144.64     76.03     61.96
02:41:02 AM       144      1279    133.04     60.48     52.53
10:06:07 AM       304      1415    128.59     72.30     51.68
12:27:01 AM       121      1399    112.99     54.63     40.77
03:20:01 AM       149      1450    120.17     58.10     36.52
/var/log/sa/sa20
10:11:01 PM       136      1449    120.49     70.64     48.13
10:12:02 PM       121      1468    143.77     87.26     55.30
10:29:01 PM        64      1362    116.96     60.23     49.71
04:07:37 AM       170      1307    110.13     46.58     35.07
03:29:01 AM        97      1217    120.40     57.09     33.87
03:30:04 AM       139      1347    165.79     81.46     43.68
03:31:05 AM       105      1379    159.32     96.09     51.29
03:32:01 AM       194      1294    153.11    105.79     57.25
```

Note that ideally it would list the filename the data was pulled from for easier tracking.

Comment: Typically, systems are set up so that sar data for each day is in its own file.  So you know the date from the name or modification time of the file, not from any data contained in the file.

Comment: Show your desired output and add some lines of `for file in /var/log/sa/sa??; do sar -q -f "$file"; done` to your question.

Comment: @larsks that is why i was trying to find a way to echo the filename() above the timestamps so that I could identify the date from which grep pulled the data.

Comment: @Cyrus Edited original post to show desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
do sar
```

by

```
do echo "$file"; sar
```

to print filename "$file" before sar's output.